# Checkstyle & Findbugs Install

Tags: java, windows

I have javac version 1.6.0_16 already installed on Windows XP and I'm using both Dr.Java and command prompt to compile and run Java programs.

I downloaded and extracted Checkstyle 5.5 and Findbugs 2.0.1.  I'm trying to install Checkstyle and the [instructions](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html) stated that I need to include checkstyle-5.5-all.jar in the classpath.

My question is, should I place the Checkstyle directory in the lib folder of the jdk1.6.0_16 directory and set the classpath as follows:

- C:>set classpath=%C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\lib\checkstyle-5.5\checkstyle-5.5-all.jar

Is this correct? Should I do the same for Findbugs? Thanks in advance

EDIT: When I added the above path using the environmental variables, and ran checkstyle hello.java, I got the error: 'checkstyle' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) will solve this problem for you**

It sounds like you're just getting started in the world of Java. To that end, I'd suggest that you look into Maven for your build process. Also, you should be using at least [JDK1.6.0_33](http://jdk6.java.net/) at the time of writing.

Essentially, Maven will manage the process of running Checkstyle, Findbugs (and you should also consider PMD) via standard plugins against your code. It will also manage the creation of the Javadocs, linked source code and generate a website for your project. Further, Maven promotes a good release process whereby you work against snapshots until ready to share your work to the wider world.

**And if I don't use Maven?**

Well, just create a `/lib` folder in your project and stuff your dependencies into it. Over time you will create more and more and these will get intertwined. After a while you will enter [JAR Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_hell#JAR_hell) and turn to Maven to solve the problem.

We've all been there.

Comment: +1 What a fantastic answer! Thanks for mentioning the fact that I need to update the JDK, recommending Maven and PMD as well as the alternative to Maven and the problems I'll run into. Great answer, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help - best of luck with your project.